# How do I check form validity with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs. Say my app has a form. Using the inspector, I noticed that if angularjs thinks that the form is invalid, it adds an ng-invalid class to the form. Lovely.

So it seems that in order to check if the form is valid I need to pollute my code with Jquery selector?! What is the angularjs way to indicate form validity without using a form controller?

Comment: "without using a form controller" Why not use a controller? That is the angular way

Answer (score 151, accepted):

When you put `<form>` tag inside you ngApp, AngularJS automatically adds form controller (actually there is a directive, called `form` that add nessesary behaviour). The value of the name attribute will be bound in your scope; so something like `<form name="yourformname">...</form>` will satisfy:

> A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can optionally be published into the scope using the name attribute.

So to check form validity, you can check value of `$scope.yourformname.$valid` property of scope.

More information you can get at [Developer's Guide section](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) about forms.

Comment: Normally it would be called inside the JS as `$scope.yourformname.$valid`.

Comment: You need to explicitly give the form some name like <form name="form">, then $scope.form should be available..

Comment: if the property doesn't seems to be defined in controller, explicitly initialize it in controller `$scope.myformname = {};`

Comment: @JohnNguyen i got the same exact error.  there's this workaround i did.  In your submit function, pass the form as an argument.  you can then go to your controller and check to see if the form is valid by yourFormName.$valid.  

They used this example in the Angular documentation, their plunker found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8mlPOSgkaPstg4uvjlc?p=preview

Comment: Make sure to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, was getting `undefined` error.

Answer (score 36):

Example

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myform">
   Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br>
   Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     //if form is not valid then return the form.
     if(!$scope.myform.$valid) {
       return;
     }
  }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `myform.$invalid`

E.g.

```
if($scope.myform.$invalid){return;}
```

Answer (score 6):

**form**

- directive in module ng
  Directive that instantiates FormController.

If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

**Alias: ngForm**

In Angular, forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is valid when all of the child forms are valid as well. However, browsers do not allow nesting of  elements, so Angular provides the ngForm directive which behaves identically to  but can be nested. This allows you to have nested forms, which is very useful when using Angular validation directives in forms that are dynamically generated using the ngRepeat directive. Since you cannot dynamically generate the name attribute of input elements using interpolation, you have to wrap each set of repeated inputs in an ngForm directive and nest these in an outer form element.

**CSS classes**

**ng-valid** is set if the form is valid.

**ng-invalid** is set if the form is invalid.

**ng-pristine** is set if the form is pristine.

**ng-dirty** is set if the form is dirty.

**ng-submitted** is set if the form was submitted.

Keep in mind that ngAnimate can detect each of these classes when added and removed.

**Submitting a form and preventing the default action**

Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.

For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:

**ngSubmit** directive on the form element

**ngClick** directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])

To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of the ngSubmit or ngClick directives.

This is because of the following form submission rules in the HTML specification:

If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
if a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or `input[type=submit]` then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or `input[type=submit]` then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or `input[type=submit]` (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit).

Any pending ngModelOptions changes will take place immediately when an enclosing form is submitted. Note that ngClick events will occur before the model is updated.

Use ngSubmit to have access to the updated model.

**app.js**:

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userType = 'guest';
  }]);
```

**Form**:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
  userType = {{userType}}
  myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}
  myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}
  myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}
  myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}
 </form>
```

Source: [AngularJS: API: form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)