# AngularJS : validate before continuing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with a workflow I'm trying to implement.

In my app I have several textboxes that are marked with a directive, like this:

```
<input type="text" data-unique-function-name
       data-is-valid="isValid"
       data-ng-model="function.Name" />
```

I have a Save button that should trigger validation in all of my UniqueFunctionName-directives, so I dispatch an event on button click like this:

```
function TriggerValidation()
{
    scope.$broadcast('uniqueFunctionName::checkUniqueFunctions');
}
```

which is handled by my directive like this:

```
 scope.$on('uniqueFunctionName::checkUniqueFunctions',
            function () {

                    functionService.validate(scope.ngModel).success(function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                             scope.isValid = false;
                            }
                });
  });
```

The scope.isValid variable is passed from my app to each and every uniqueFunctionName directive. If any of the above validations would fail, the isValid would be changed to `false`.

What I'm trying to do now is to trigger the Validation when the user presses the save button, and only if scope.isValid is still true after that continue. I've tried this, but it obviously doesn't work.

```
TriggerValidation(); //dispatch the event
if (scope.isValid) {
  //continue
} else {
  //display error message
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try setting `scope.isValid = true` before dispatching the event?

Comment: Yes. but the if statement will just continue then without being sure that all the validation has finished, right?

Comment: You should follow the ngModel stuff, so validation should be done on the fly. When you validate you could add a property to look at to see if the validation is successful. Dispatching out to a directive from your controller is not really a good way to go about this.

Comment: I see! Thank you. I now realize I already do this with my scope.isValid. I set this to false when an error is found. I can just check for this. However, I now see that if I change the value to 'false', that the change isn't detected. Scope.isValid in my app is still 'true'. Happen to know why that might be?

Comment: There are ways to get OP's approach to work, but I submit that this is reinventing the wheel. My answer recommends using Angular's facilities for form validation.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's built in!

Everything you need to do this is available in Angular, but it's not immediately obvious how. First, according to the [AngularJS Forms Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state), you should surround your `<input />` elements with a form with a name attribute. For example:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.userName" name="userName" />
</form>
```

Now, within your controller's $scope, you can access an [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) instance using `$scope.myForm`, which has many useful properties. For example, the  [`$valid` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$valid).

You could use this in your controller as simply as:

```
if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
  // do something with the comfort that all your fields are validated
}
```

[See this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299834/how-do-i-check-form-validity-with-angularjs)

You can also access individual input's validation status (assuming you supplied a name attribute for those too), using something `$scope.myForm.userName.$valid`.

The great part is this is running after each model update, so there is no need to dispatch a custom event. Angular will run the validation code and set the variables for you, which erases your problem with trying get asynchronous code to behave synchronously.

#### Custom Validation

If you don't need any special validation on your inputs other than what Angular provides (email, number, url, etc.), simply add the [appropriate attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and Angular will do the right thing, making the results available on the FormController's $valid and $error properties.

There is a pretty simple way to make [custom validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) (see the integer example for a trivial example). I haven't actually written a more complex validator than that, so I'll leave explaining more of that to the Angular documentation and other Stackoverflow answers.