# Angular autovalidate form validation message?

Tags: angularjs

How can i use to angular auto-validate before submitting to base. I want to click on submit button when all inputs is empty and i want to message then. I use this:

```
 <form role="form" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="submit()" ng-submit-force="true">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check form validity with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299834/how-do-i-check-form-validity-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically creates `.$valid` for your form if you give it a name.
You therefore can stop your form from submiting by checking the `$valid`

```
<form method="POST" name = "myForm" role="form" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submit()" novalidate >
    <!-- All your Form stuff-->
</form>
```

Comment: '<form name="addlesson" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="addlesson.$valid && submit()" >'

Comment: do you have `method="POST"` in your form?

Comment: <form name="addlesson" role="form" method="POST" ng-submit="addlesson.$valid && submit()" novalidate>

Comment: What is your exact Problem?
Have you looked at the validation section of the official video tutorial?
 http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/3/section/3/video/1

Comment: I need message that my inputs are empty when i click button submit now when i click this button i got only message from database from rules section in yii2. I need this message from js angular when i click on my button

Comment: i want do this without controller just i view can i do this?

Comment: actually I don't know if this is possible without a controller/module