# Disabled submit button if form is invalid angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I currently have a form with many different inputs. In the example below I have created a form with two inputs for simplicity. I am trying to make it so my submit button is disabled when the form isn't valid - that is, when all the `required` inputs have not been filled out.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" required/>
  <input type="number" placeholder="age" required />
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
  {{ myForm.$invalid }} <!-- prints "false" -->
</form>
```

As you can see from the above snippet, `myForm.$invalid` is `false` even though I haven't filled out the required inputs yet. Is there some different property which will tell me if the required inputs have all been filled out?

I have looked at different posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299834/how-do-i-check-form-validity-with-angularjs) but when I try and use `myForm.$valid` it just gives me the negated version of `myForm.$invalid`, which doesn't help much either.

Comment: add a class which has disabled css property. Add and  call a method , which is defined in controller , from  each input box on change and valid the form if all input fields are valid then remove the class dynamically  or add the  class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `ng-model` in the form fields. You need to add [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) as it detects the changes in the form fields.

Try this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="name" required/>
  <input type="number" ng-model="age" placeholder="age" required />
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
  {{ myForm.$invalid }} <!-- prints "false" -->
</form>
```